# How to do factor analysis for categorical data?

Tags: categorical-data, factor-analysis

Now I have two data set which is generated by two listing flow of a e-commerce site. And these data set has different conversion rate, my task is to analysis the two data set and found out which factors lead the different conversion rate. BTW, most of the data is categorical data. Could you help point me some tutorial or method that I can refer to do the analysis ? Currently what I did is just according my intuition, I'd like to find out to some systematic method for factory analysis of categorical data.

Answer (score -1):

You could try Multidimensional Scaling, it is a technique to "transform" a set of points, where you have a distance on two points, into a set of euclidean vectors in such a way that the distances are nearly equal. 
If the points of this set are already vectors, then this technique is identical to Principal Component Analysis.
Once you have your "points" transformed into Euclidean vectors, you could do Factor Analysis.
For the distance in your points you could use the Gower Coefficient which mixes categorical and ordinal variables.

Multidimensional Scaling: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multidimensional_scaling
Gower Coefficient : http://venus.unive.it/romanaz/modstat_ba/gowdis.pdf

Both are implemented in R, so you do not have to implement them on your own, but reading the articles is encouraged to understand what the implementation does.
( Gower R :  Google "daisy r gower" ,
(Classical) MDS : Google "r multidimensional scaling" )